# Can't install bundler, shows version too old

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am trying to install wpscan to my system, but it shows an error to the ruby version for some reason, however it is sufficient for this install(>=2.3.0)

Error:

```
[root@ds wpscan]# gem install bundler
ERROR:  Error installing bundler:
        bundler requires Ruby version >= 2.3.0.
[root@ds wpscan]# ruby -v
ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux]
[root@ds wpscan]#
```

Comment: are you using rvm / rbenv? they recommend to have at least rvm

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've got multiple ruby installs and that `gem` is coming from the wrong one.

Try running `which ruby` and `which gem` to see if they can point you in the right direction.